# How to display a notification banner when developing a tweak with theos?

Tags: storyboard, jailbreak, tweak, theos

I use theos developing a tweak. I hook the storyboard and want to display a notification banner, like what Activator did when changing the state.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at SBRemoteNotificationServer and move from there: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SBRemoteNotificationServer